# Installing Python modules on MacOSX

Tags: python-3.x, http, pip, python-requests

I'm trying to install the http library through the command "pip install http".

It give me this error:
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

I just installed setuptools but it doesn't work anyway.

EDIT:
when I launch the command '`pip3 install http`' I get this:

```
 pip3 install http
Collecting http
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/91/a9260805e532e33df273b8f7dffad5c51693f8f9ba5f86bedcf42a7f22eb/http-0.02.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/1v/xm2qv7l132sghltfqm3q15wm0000gn/T/pip-install-g44pke5e/http/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import http
      File "/private/var/folders/1v/xm2qv7l132sghltfqm3q15wm0000gn/T/pip-install-g44pke5e/http/http/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from request import Request
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Request'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/1v/xm2qv7l132sghltfqm3q15wm0000gn/T/pip-install-g44pke5e/http/
```

I tried many times to check and upload requests package but when I do it I get this:

```
pip3 install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2018.4.16)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (1.23)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2.7)
```

Somebody knows what I made wrong with it?

Comment: Please post the whole error message

Comment: @ForceBru I edited my question, does it help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http` version 0.02 [was released](https://pypi.org/project/http/#history) in 2012. The [homepage](https://github.com/franckcuny/http) returns error 404.

I think the package is simply abandoned, broken and outdated. Avoid it or fork it and update it yourself.

Comment: I wanted to use the httplib but it seems that its name has been changed in http.client for Python 3. It doesn't work anyway.

Comment: That's [http from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html), you don't need to install it, it comes with Python.